# "unbound method textFile() must be called with SparkContext instance as first argument (got str instance instead)"

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to use the sc.textFile() function to read a csv file. However I am getting the "unbound method textFile() must be called with SparkContext instance as first argument (got str instance instead)" error. I checked within stackoverflow for possible answers but couldnt find any answers. Please help

I am using the below script in iPython Notebook

```
import os.path

from pyspark import SparkContext


import csv


basedir = os.path.join('data') 

inputpath = os.path.join('train_set.csv') 

filename = os.path.join(basedir,inputpath)

numpart = 2

sc = SparkContext

train_data = sc.textFile(filename,numpart)
```

#### Just to clarify, basedir ('data') is the folder where the csv file resides. Please help

Comment: You're calling it as a class method but it's really an instance method. Instantiate SparkContext and then call it. Change `sc = SparkContext` to `sc = SparkContext()`

Comment: Thanks. I tried as you suggested, and got a different error "cannot run multiple sparkcontexts at once; existing sparkcontext(app=pysparkshell, master=local[*])" . So I removed the SparkContext definition ( sc = SparkContext) and it started working. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 10):

First, thanks for your question, I used the answer to find a solution to the same kind of problem. I want to answer to your 11 Aug 2015 comment.

You might have a look at what happens in your command shell behind the notebook for getting an explanation.

When you first call:

```
sc=SparkContext()
```

you will see `Spark` being initialized, pretty as much as when you just launch `Spark` from the command shell.
So you initialize `sc` (by default at the launch of `Spark`)

If you call it a second time, you have the error you speak of in your comment. So I would say you already had a `Spark` context `sc` initialized the first time you tried the suggestion (or maybe you ran the suggestion twice).

The reason why it is working when you remove the `SparkContext` definition is because `sc` is defined, but the next time you launch your `IPython` notebook, I think you will have to run `sc = SparkContext()` one time.

To make it clearer, I would say that the code, from an `IPython Notebook` point of view, would be organized as follow:

One cell that is run once each time you restart the kernel to customize your `Python` environment and initialize your `Spark` environment:

```
import os.path
import csv
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext()
```

A second cell that you run multiple times for testing purpose:

```
basedir = os.path.join('data') 
inputpath = os.path.join('train_set.csv') 
filename = os.path.join(basedir,inputpath)
numpart = 2
train_data = sc.textFile(filename,numpart)
```

But if you want one cell, you could also call the `stop()` method on the `SparkContext` object at the end of your code:

```
#your initialization
import os.path
import csv
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext()
#your job
basedir = os.path.join('data') 
inputpath = os.path.join('train_set.csv') 
filename = os.path.join(basedir,inputpath)
numpart = 2
train_data = sc.textFile(filename,numpart)
#closing the SparkContext
sc.stop()
```

I really advise the O'Reilly book [*Learning Spark Lightning-fast data analysis*](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/learning-spark/9781449359034/) by Holden Karau, Andy Konwinski, Patrick Wendell & Matei Zaharia. Particularly the Chapter 2 for this kind of question about understanding *Core `Spark` Concepts*.

Maybe you know this now, apologize if it is but it might help someone else !